# '=' sign in Json gives parser execption

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting the following exception while deserializing the JSON.

Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: M. Path '', line 1, position 1

Here is my code:

```
var SomeCollections = [
    {
        "id": 50,
        "title": "A Test (RK)",
        "cards": [
            {
                "id": 155,
                "title": "Swimming Turtles",
                "description": "We're swimming, swimming, swimming .......",
                "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MsU1V3X294",
                "alt": "swimming turtles",
                "order": 5,
                "type": "Photo"
            }
        ],
        "templateId": 4,
        "startTime": "09/26/2014 23:42",
        "endTime": "10/06/2015 07:00",
        "status": "live"
    }
]


var value = JSON.stringify(SomeCollections);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/path/SomeHandler.ashx?method=SomeMethod",
            data: value,
            dataType: "json"            
        });
```

### Code behind

```
string collectionJSON = context.Request.Form[0];
List<CCollection> collections = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CCollection>>    (collectionJSON, new MyDateTimeConvertor());
```

If I remove the '=' sign in the url, this is working correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The path points you to: line 1, position 1 (so the fact that your JSON object, starts with an array is your error)

Comment: You have a get url using `POST`. Should be more like: `data: {method:'SomeMethod', json:value}`. I would change your entire approach, if possible, to make it easier to get that information Server Side.

Comment: @PHPglue: he is using a .net webrequest handler, those expect parts over a get, and a post data (since the webservice itself contains all methods, the get helps the service to get to the correct method to run, the post data is then parsed to provide the basic parameters for this function). Though i would prefer to see the full code behind code (or at least the top class definition & the method declaration before i would give a more permanent answer on the question :))

Comment: @Icepickle: Yes. That's correct

Comment: Why are you using `var SomeCollections = ` in the beginning of the JSON? This is not Javascript!